# Best practice to resolve Now() vs timezone.now() sync differences across databse and web workers?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I have a [checkconstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint) on a django model, applied on a PostgreSQL database:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import CheckConstraint, Q, F
from django.db.models.functions import Now

class Event(models.Model):
    mydate = models.DatetimeField() 

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                check = Q(mydate__lte=Now()), 
                name = 'check_my_date',
            ),
        ]
```

The constraint ensures that `mydate` can not be in the future, but constraining it to be less than [Now()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/database-functions/#now) which returns the start of the transaction time on the PostgreSQL server.

I set `mydate` programmatically in the app:

```
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()
myevent = Event.objects.create(mydate=now)
```

However, this will often fail the checkconstraint. I assume this is because the setup I am using is Heroku, with a separate PostgreSQL and worker (app) instance. The PostgreSQL `Now()` timestamp appears to run a few seconds behind the web worker.

What is best practice to sync/resolve this conflict?

Comment: Since you want to put the current time in there why not use `Event.objects.create(mydate=Now())`?

Comment: Actually from here [Now()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/database-functions/#now): " **PostgreSQL considerations** On PostgreSQL, the SQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns the time that the current transaction started. Therefore for cross-database compatibility, Now() uses STATEMENT_TIMESTAMP instead.If you need the transaction timestamp, use django.contrib.postgres.functions.TransactionNow."